# React component not refreshing state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching all contest rows and setting the contestRows state array. I then check the rows against the cntsts array. If the row has a completely new contestID, I add a new contest into the cntsts array. If the contestID already exists, I add a league to that contest's contestLeagues array a property.

After checking all the rows, I then set the contests state array to the cntsts array. The state array always ends up looking correct but when I map the contests array it doesn't render the table rows consistently.

Here is the entire component

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Row, Col, Table, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

/*
   Fetch open contests, create List Item for each contest. Populate with details 
   Contest Object : 
        {
            contestID: Number, 
            contestLeagues: [
                {
                    leagueID: Number, 
                    leagueName: String
                }   
            ],
            entry: Number, 
            bankroll: Number, 
            prizepool: Number,
            start: Date, 
            end: Date, 
            minPlayers: Number, 
            maxPlayers: Number
        }
*/

const OpenContests = (props) => {
    const [contestRows, setContestRows] = useState([]);
    const [contests, setContests] = useState([]);

    //fetch open contests on initial render
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchOpenContests = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/contests/open');
            const data = await response.json(); 
            setContestRows(data);
        }

        fetchOpenContests();
    },[]);

    //run when contest rows array changes 
    useEffect(()=>{
        let cntsts = [];
        let count = 1;
        if(contestRows.length > 0){
            contestRows.forEach(row=> {
                cntsts = checkRow(row);
                count = count++;
            })
            if(count === contestRows.length){
                setContests(cntsts);
            }
        }
    },[contestRows]);
    
    //Check row and update contests, either adding a league to an existing contest or adding a new contest
    const checkRow = (row) => {
        let arr = contests;
        let index = contests.findIndex(contest=> contest.contestID === row.intContestID);
        if(index > -1){
            let league = {
                leagueID: row.intLeagueID, 
                leagueName: row.strLeagueName
            }

            arr[index].contestLeagues = [...arr[index].contestLeagues, league];
            console.log(index)
        }else{
            arr.push({
                contestID: row.intContestID, 
                contestType: row.strContestType,
                contestLeagues: [
                    {
                        leagueID: row.intLeagueID, 
                        leagueName: row.strLeagueName
                    }   
                ],
                entry: row.decEntryFee, 
                bankroll: row.decInitialBankRoll, 
                prizepool: row.decPrizePool,
                start: row.dtmStart, 
                end: row.dtmEnd, 
                minPlayers: '', 
                maxPlayers: ''
            })
        }
        return [...arr];

    }; 


    //Enter contest 
    const enterContest = async (contestID) => {
        const body = {
            contestID: contestID,
            accountID: props.accountID
        };

        const opts = {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"        
            }
        }

        const url = "/contests/enter";

        //enter contest
        fetch(url, opts)
        .then(response=> {
            console.log(response.json())
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    console.log(contests.length);

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <h3>Open Contests</h3>
                    <Table striped bordered hover>  
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Contest</td>
                                <td>Type</td>
                                <td>Entry Fee</td>
                                <td>Prizepool</td>
                                <td>Entries</td>
                                <td>Bankroll</td>
                                <td>Start</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>               
                        <tbody>   
                            {contests.map(contest=>{
                                console.log(contest)
                                return(
                                    <tr key={contest.contestID}>
                                        <td>Contest Name TBD</td>
                                        <td>{contest.contestType}</td>
                                        <td>${contest.entry}</td>
                                        <td>${contest.prizepool}</td>
                                        <td>Entries(need calculated)</td>
                                        <td>${contest.bankroll}</td>
                                        <td>{contest.start}</td>
                                        <td><Button onClick={()=>alert("details")}>Details</Button></td>
                                        <td><Button onClick={()=>enterContest(contest.contestID)}>Enter</Button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>            
                </Col>    
            </Row>     
        )

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        accountID: state.user.ID
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OpenContests);
```

Here is the contests state array when the table rows load. 
[image]

Here is the contests state array when the table rows don't load. 
[image]

Can someone explain why this is not rendering. It just seems like the state variable is not triggering a rerender and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are you ever executing this line: `setContests(cntsts);`?

Comment: Nope, Iol I found the issue. count = count++ isnt valid, just count++ is necessary. That fixed the issue. Still odd that the table would sometimes display even though the contests array was never being set, and the array was always populated as well?? Oh well, thanks.